# How do I manage different celery config files on various nodes in a cluster?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have a cluster of celery nodes with different celery configurations (celeryconfig.py & celery.py) along with different start & stop scripts. It is getting cumbersome to manage the different files.

Right now I hacked up my ansible automation to incorporate different config files but this seems dirty and will not scale.

Is there any way to handle all different configurations, a centralized way to manage the config files?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is usually pretty good at this kind of thing.

There are several ways you can deal with this:

- have a per-host config file and get ansible to create a symlink `/path/to/celeryconfig.py --> /path/to/configs/<hostname>-celeryconfig.py`
- same as previous but on a per-group basis
- use ansible templates to tweak particular parts of a generic template config file depending on host/group/whatever
- etc...

Comment: I have been using ansible templates until now, but it has lead to too many templates and this configuration does not seem scalable. Is there any apache zookeper sort of solution?

Comment: I've done similar setups where I've had only 1 template file for e.g. `celeryconfig.py` and ansible logic created the correct version on each host. You may be using ansible in a sub-optimal manner. To answer your question - yes there are several like zookeeper. I am assuming that zookeeper itself does not suit you for some reason - we are currently trialing `etcd` with promising results.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am configuring my ansible scripts sub-optimally, I shall look into it and try to incorporate best practices. 

I would be highly grateful if you could share some best practices about managing the celeryconfig.py, celery.py, celery start/stop scripts (which include queues parameter). Thanks again!

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question. I'd suggest e.g. explaining how you handle `celeryconfig.py` (omit the other files to keep the question simple) and ask if there's a better way to handle this in ansible